# Why printer doesn't print automatically in the case of 'out of paper' ? It must need to press ok button for each time..

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I can't print pages automatically by giving the paper when it was out of paper, I must need to press ok button after giving the paper into the printer. the printer is HP LaserJet Pro M201dw IP Printer.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, the following happens:

1. you begin printing something
2. a few pages come out fine
3. printer exhausts its supply of paper
4. printing stops
5. you approach the printer
6. you open the empty paper tray
7. you add paper
8. you close the tray
9. you press the OK button
10. printing resumes

You want to know why step 9 has to be done?

What if it automatically started printing again as soon as you put the paper tray back in?

Well, what would happen then if you accidentally loaded the wrong paper, and realized that quickly enough that you pull the tray back out.  The printer has already started to try and grab a page which means it could jam, or damage to part of the loading mechanism could occur.

I'm not saying there is no way to make the printer smart enough to hesitate or use some other means to safely resume on its own.  I've used some printers which did automatically resume.  They were definitely not without issues, and I cleaned many a jam caused by a user shoving the drawer in and then pulling it back out to check or load more.

Hitting OK signals the printer that yes, you are finished messing around with its various pieces and parts and are ready for it to safely get back to work.

Comment: but there is a problem in the case of remote printing.... physical pressing ok is not possible. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

This behavior occurs if you print to a specific tray, and that tray runs out of paper. It is possible to setup the printer according to papertype. If you do this, multiple trays can be used for the same kind of paper, and if one tray then runs out, the other tray will automatically take over without the user to require to press OK.

## But pressing OK will make it print?

When you go to the printer, the display will tell you that it can't print to xxx, and that pressing OK will make the print use the next available tray. You are hereby overriding the default setting, which is why the printer asks you to confirm.

## Alternate scenario

This is related to the answer but not applicable in this case. I mention it here just because it may help some.

If you specify certain properties for the document you are printing, while on the printer side you specify different but similar properties, the printer will also halt and asks for confirmation.

For example: tray 1 is set with Legal size, while the document you print is set with A4 size. The printer will get a request to print on A4, doesn't see a tray that supports it, so instead of blindly printing to Tray 1, it will say: uh, are you sure?

Comment: Some printers also want you to press OK to confirm that you have loaded the correct paper type (plain, letterhead, etc). In that case there is usually a message on the display to prompt you.

Comment: but there is a problem in the  case of remote printing.... physical pressing ok is not possible.

Comment: @techITezZy Yes, that's why you need to properly configure the printer to match the same paper type in the various trays in the printer's configuration, then make sure you change your printer settings on windows to print to: tray=automatically select, papertype=normal, preprinted, etc. A properly configured printer will not make you press the ok button. Thats my point.